# The following _TypeError was thrown building: type 'MappedListIterable<AkcijeDokument, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching list of documents from api and every document has property actions(List of actions). Documents are displayed in a List and i want to display actions in ActionPane/SlidableAction an I get an error: "Another exception was thrown: type 'MappedListIterable<AkcijeDokument, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'".
And error "The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'MappedListIterable<AkcijeDokument, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'"...

When I print actions like this `params[index].akcije.map((ak) => print(ak.nazivAkcije))` I get response: "I/flutter (25152): Potvrdi
I/flutter (25152): Odbij", "Potvrdi" and "Odbij" are the actions that i need to fetch and display in List for each document.

And here is the code where I'm trying to display the actions

````
params[index].akcije.map<Widget>(
      (ak) => SlidableAction(
        onPressed: (context) {},
        icon: Icons.bookmark,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        label: ak.nazivAkcije,
       ),
     ),,```
````

Answer (score 2):

First error is because you use `map<Widget>()` when the type you have in. a map is `{AkcjeDokument, dynamic}`

If what you want is to just print them use `.map()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
List<Widget> ak_list;
  for (var ak in params[index].akcije) {
    ak_list.add(SlidableAction(
        onPressed: (context) {},
        icon: Icons.bookmark,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        label: ak.nazivAkcije,
    ));
 }
```

and use

```
//example after init
Column(children: ak_list);
```